# Is it known what input for sha256 would yield the same result as no input?

Tags: hash, sha-256

As the title says: do we know already for sha256 what input would yield the same output as when using no input at all?

Comment: The empty string ≠ no input.

Comment: Two distinct inputs with the same output is a collision. We know of no collisions in SHA-2. (in practice it'd even amount to a second pre-image, which we can't even construct for MD5)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Semantically, this makes no sense.

> A function $\ f : X \to Y$, always takes an *input* from $X$ (by definition of a function).

In the case of $SHA256$ the set of possible inputs is the list of all possible bit strings, **including the empty string** denoted as $\epsilon$ :

$X = \{\\
\epsilon,\\
\texttt{0b0},\\
\texttt{0b1},\\
\texttt{0b00}\\
\texttt{0b01},\\
\texttt{0b10},\\
\ldots\}$

**Remark:** this is not a finite set.

As a result, there is no such thing as *no input at all*.

---

If your question is

> Do we know $x$ such that $SHA256(x) = SHA256(\epsilon)$ where $\epsilon$ is the empty string ?

Then the answer is no, because this is called a collision ($x \neq y \land h(x) = h(y)$) and none has been found (yet) for SHA256.

Comment: I have seen the empty string denoted $\lambda$, $\epsilon$, or $\varepsilon$, but never $\sigma$...

Comment: SHA-2 is defined for all *bit* strings, the length doesn't need to be a multiple of 8 bits.

Comment: @fanael true but that's is not really relevant with respect to the semantic meaning of no inputs.

Comment: Oh, sure, it's an unrelated thing, but I'd really like to see people get this correctly.

Comment: By the way, strictly speaking, SHA-256 is limited to 2⁶⁴-1 bits, so the set of all inputs is finite.

Comment: I won't bother with correcting that one :)